# Get the @language tag from a SPARQL request

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I use http://dbpedia.org/sparql to do this request:

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?trad
where{
res:Apple
rdfs:label ?trad
}
```

which returns me the following result:

[image]

How do I get the language tag (@ar, @es, @fr) in a separated column?

I've seen on w3.org something that could maybe help:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

SPARQL documentation contains everything about SPARQL, thus, it's always the most appropriate source to dig into.

In your case, the part about [the language of an RDF term](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lang) is useful.

```sql
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?trad (lang(?trad) as ?lang) WHERE {
  res:Apple rdfs:label ?trad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To assemble "@fr", "@es", and "@ar" language tag values into one table, with separated columns, try the SPARQL [UNION](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#alternatives) keyword, and [FILTER](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lang) with the language function on each variable:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?french ?spanish ?arabic

where{ { dbr:Apple rdfs:label ?french  FILTER ( lang(?french) = "fr" ) }
UNION
{ dbr:Apple rdfs:label ?spanish   FILTER ( lang(?spanish) = "es" ) }
UNION
{ dbr:Apple rdfs:label ?arabic   FILTER ( lang(?arabic) = "ar" ) }}
```